# svg mirror paths without changing coordinates

Tags: svg, matrix, transform

i have an svg graphic but wanted to mirror it without changing the coordinates of the line/stroke but swap the position of the arrowhead and circle… is there a more efficient way of doing this? one thing that i thought about is changing the angle of each arrowhead and circle but is tedious to do. another suggestion is using `transform matrix`. does anybody know how to do this? thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg width="2000" height="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<g>
<path fill="none" stroke="#4caf50" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M195.2,75.3c28-11.5,60.9-18.1,96-18.1 c78.4,0,145.6,32.9,173.1,79.4" />
 <g fill="#4caf50" id="test">
  <polygon class="one" points="201.6,79 202.1,77.7 195.7,75.1 198.8,68.9 197.5,68.3 193.8,75.9"/>
  <path class="two" d="M461.6,138.1c0.8,1.4,2.7,1.9,4.1,1.1s1.9-2.7,1.1-4.1c-0.8-1.4-2.7-1.9-4.1-1.1 C461.3,134.8,460.8,136.6,461.6,138.1z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: model the arrowhead and circle as markers and you can then put them on the end of any shape you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with the help of `SVG` markers. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) and  [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg width="2000" height="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs> 
  <marker id="arrow1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="#4caf50" />
    </marker>
      <marker id="circle1" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5"
           markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#4caf50""  />
      </marker>
 </defs

<g>
<path fill="none" stroke="#4caf50" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M195.2,75.3c28-11.5,60.9-18.1,96-18.1 c78.4,0,145.6,32.9,173.1,79.4"  style=" marker-start: url(#circle1); marker-end: url(#arrow1); 
      fill:none; stroke:green; stroke-width:2; " />
 
</svg>
```

### Update

The angle of the marker can be changed using the attribute `orient = ("180")`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg width="2000" height="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs> 
  <marker id="arrowLeft" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="170"
        markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="#4caf50" />
    </marker>
 
  <marker id="arrowRight" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="#4caf50" />
    </marker>
  
      <marker id="circle1" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5"
           markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto"
            markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#4caf50"  />
      </marker>
 </defs>


<path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="#4caf50" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M195.2,75.3c28-11.5,60.9-18.1,96-18.1 c78.4,0,145.6,32.9,173.1,79.4"  style=" marker-end: url(#arrowRight); marker-start: url(#circle1); 
      fill:none; stroke:green; stroke-width:2; " />  
   
  <g transform="translate(0 100)" >
 <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="#4caf50" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M195.2,75.3c28-11.5,60.9-18.1,96-18.1 c78.4,0,145.6,32.9,173.1,79.4"  style=" marker-end: url(#circle1); marker-start: url(#arrowLeft); 
      fill:none; stroke:green; stroke-width:2; " />  
   
  </g> 
   
   
 
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you. how can i reuse it multiple times with different angles particularly the arrowhead?

Comment: @telo78 To mirror the markers, swap their unique identifiers `marker-start` and `marker-end` . You can use the same markers multiple times to reuse markers on multiple lines.

Comment: @telo78 I add example

Comment: @Alexander_T works for simpler animation but if i have one hundred animating arrows, the orient attribute needs to be per arrowhead too, right? unless i can rotate the same arrowhead multiple times when using it inside the path?

Comment: @telo78 Yes, you can rotate the marker at different angles for each line. But you still need two types of markers arrows left direction and right. Play with my second example and it will be clear.

Comment: @telo78 It's easier to draw two kinds of arrow markers at once - for the left and right directions. The attribute for both arrow markers will be the same. `Orient = "auto"`  And then it will not be necessary to track the marker angle for each arrow.

Comment: @Alexander_T undertand that there are 2 kinds of rotation but what if one arrowhead is 6deg and is not on the same x axis? meaning it is used in a different arrow line or path... where do i declare the transform property of the same marker in the path? that would mean adding another defs marker? say i have 100 animating arrows with different size paths hence different endpoints for the arrowheads.

Comment: @telo78 attribute of the marker orient = "auto" provides automatic following of the arrow direction along the direction of the line. The transformation of the rotation of the marker in this case is not needed.  You can manually adjust the position of the marker relative to the path `refX="0"` `refY="10"` Above, I added links to marker theory. Please read the articles

Comment: thank you. i reviewed the article and tested your example with mine. i had issues with some cases were i created a smaller path, the arrowLeft set to auto orient did not line up along the end or start of the path. as well as i created a custom path as a marker for a wider path example and circles. https://codepen.io/tfss/pen/aXpvQj